# Did I "say" that online, or did I "write" it?

Tags: word-choice, formality, quotations

When we refer to something someone else has previously spoken or written, we usually differentiate between the spoken and written word with the verb introducing the quote or paraphrase:

> In his speech at Cooper Union, Abraham Lincoln **said**, "Human action can be modified to some extent, but human nature cannot be changed."

vs.

> In the letter to Trebonius, Cicero **wrote**, "How I could wish that you had invited me to that most glorious banquet on the Ides of March!"

I've noticed when writing online in conversation-like settings, such as comments threads or text chats, I almost invariably use *said* rather that *wrote*:

> Q: what time is the party
>
> A: same as i **said** before. 7:30.

When I take the time to redraft—something I do with comments, but not with chats—I always wrestle with these. I change *said* to *wrote*, but when used to refer back to words in "chatty" media, it just reads *wrong* to me.

It seems as if some intangible but intrinsic quality attaches to various media, spurring me to prefer *write* for referring to emails, long-form blog posts, essays, articles, and papers, but *say* for back-and-forth comments and chats.

Is my intuition about this shared by others? Would you bristle at seeing my comment,

> ...as I **said** in a comment yesterday...

or would this not bother you? Should I try forcing myself to substitute *wrote* for *said* whenever referring to words not spoken aloud?

Comment: Although [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/say) lists the 'by mouth' sense for 'say' first, it gives the general word-based communication second: **say**: 1. to speak, pronounce, or utter
2. (also intr) to express (an idea) in words ... // To specify the actual medium of communication, one might well say: 'As I said in my email on Thursday, ...'.

Comment: Citing a dictionary definition and stating why it didn't help are pretty much minimal requirements for questions like this. *To write* is one way to say something, and narrows down how the thought was expressed. *To say* is not so definitive. A more useful question might be *how can I express the verbal meaning of "to say" in as few words as possible?*

Comment: @CanisLupus "How can I express the verbal meaning of 'to say' in as few words as possible?" But that _isn't my question_. If my question isn't well-phrased, I'm happy to take advice on how to rewrite it, but telling me to ask a different question isn't helpful.

Comment: Putting my comment more plainly, then - your question does not show the minimal amount of effort expected to show that you have performed your own research that leads anyone to understand why that research puts you in your irreconcilable position. Refer to [the help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), specifically the topic *there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”* and the subject on commonly available references. Rewriting your question may avoid this.

Comment: I write, you have all but answered your own question by writing you'd have to force yourself. If it doesn't come naturally, then what you're trying to do is unnatural.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did read the help center before asking this, but I missed the section about describing the research done prior. Actually I still can't find it, can you point me more specifically? I did do searches and checked the "say" and "write" entries in three online dictionaries and the one on my Mac, and checked the Oxford American Usage. I also did some Google searches that I hoped would turn up an answer but did not. Should I enumerate all these in the question?

Comment: @CanisLupus I will edit the question to list all the things I did before asking. But it would be a copyright issue for me to quote what each source said, wouldn't it? I've been clicking around recently-answered questions and I haven't found _any_ that list the prior research, so a link to an example would be helpful so I can see the form this is expected in. (I suspect this is like the days when Wikipedia first started requiring good references—most people didn't know, and people who knew didn't know how.)

Comment: @RegDwigнt That's plainly not true for me... I grew up in the Southern United States where there's a vernacular second-person plural pronoun, "y'all". I'm twenty years removed from living there and it _still_ sounds unnatural every single time I use the word "you" to refer to multiple people, but I force myself to do it because that's required in all but the most casual contexts.